# What are permissions required to call(launch) other apps like whatsapp in my case from our app

Tags: java, android, xml

My code:

```
Button buton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


public void onClick(View arg0) {

   Intent inte = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
   if (inte != null)
      startActivity(inte);
   else
      toast.show();
```

Comment: Ask the developers of the app that you want to launch. In general, you do not need permissions to start a launcher activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any permission, you can just launch it through an intent.
Pay attention, in some cases this might lead to app being refused from the Store (If you invoke another app - like whatsapp - since it might not be fully permitted by whatsapp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify if the activity of another app that you are willing to run is exported or not.
The launcher activity of whatsapp is surely exported so you probably don't need any permission.